# Setting database values conditionally in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

Essentially:

- I want to set the `title` of a revision to the title of the post it is a revision of.
- I want to set the `revision_id` to the `id` if the new post is not a revision (or `is_revision = false`)

So far, I'm having a lot of trouble with this. Any help appreciated.

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :revisions, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "revision_id"
belongs_to :revision, class_name: "Post"

#...

before_save :post_title

def post_title
  if :is_revision == false
    @revision_id = @post_id
  elsif :is_revision == true
    :revision_id != :post_id
    @title = @revision.title
  end
end

#...

end
```

**Update**

I am now able to get this working through the controller. Should I still aim to make this work occur in the model? The same code is under create and update actions.

posts_controller.rb

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
    if @post.is_revision == false
      @post.revision_id = @post.id
      @post.save
    elsif @post.is_revision == true
      @post.title = @post.revision.title
      @post.save
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: The syntax `if :is_revision == false` is wrong. You are comparing a symbol to a boolean. Try running your code in the console with a model instance to be sure you're calling methods correctly.

Comment: In this case, would i call `@revision_id` or `self.revision_id`?

Comment: @aceofspades : I am _now_ able to get this to work through the controller, however, it would be ideal to have this in the model. Any suggestions. I'll update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your logic there, maybe you should tell us some context.

Otherwise, did you simply try:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :revisions, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "revision_id"
belongs_to :revision, class_name: "Post"

#...

before_save :set_title_to_revision_title, :if => :is_revision?

# Need to be called after the save because post.id will not be available on the create
after_save :update_revision_id_to_id, :unless => :is_revision?

def is_revision?
  @is_revision
end

def set_title_to_revision_title
  @title = @revision.title 
end

def update_revision_id_to_id
  # just make a quick call to update it i
  update_attribute :revision_id, @id
end

#...

end
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know. A user can choose if their post will be a new post or a revision of another (via the `is_revision` Boolean). When it's a post, I want to fill the foreign key id (`revision_id`) with the id. When it's a revision, I want to use the title of the post it is a revision of. These posts are uploaded works in progress and the revisions are proving tricky to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure this recursivity is the best way to achieve what you want. I mean, if it's a post it's by definition not a revision, so you should not fill `revision_id`. Instead having a `is_revision` column in your database, you could just modify the method `is_revision?` so that it returns `@revision_id.nil?`, and you could even make a scope `:revisions` to query all posts that are revisions. Also I think you misnamed the column `revision_id`, actualy `revision_id` refers to a revision, but in this case you are refering to the parent post, I'd named it `parent_id` or `post_id` if I were you.